# How can I access a nested item for a Helm charts custom value file?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the `stable/prometheus` helm chart and I've configured a custom values file that further configures alertmanager for the chart deployment. I can install the chart via Helm3 without any issues, however, there's one thing I'm not able to figure out. For the `Slack Reciever/slack_configs/api_url` I want to pass that through the `set` command so I don't have to keep it hardcoded into file.

I hope I'm on the right path, and here's what I'm thinking of running to access the value.

```
helm install test-release stable/prometheus -f customALM.yml --set alertmanagerFiles.alertmanager.yml.receivers[0].api_url=https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**`customALM.yml`**

```
alertmanagerFiles:
  alertmanager.yml:
        route:
          group_wait: 10s
          group_interval: 5m
          repeat_interval: 30m
          receiver: "slack"

          routes:
            - receiver: "slack"
              group_wait: 10s
              match_re:
                severity: error|warning
              continue: true

        receivers:
          - name: "slack"
            slack_configs:
              - api_url: '[howDoIsetThisAtTheCLI?'
                channel: 'someChannel'
                text: "Text message template etc."
```

**Update 4/8:** I'm making progress thanks to willro! I'm able to get a value inserted but it puts it at the root of the alertmanager block. I've tried a few different combinations to access receivers/slack_configs but no luck yet =/

```
helm install test-release stable/prometheus -f customALM.yml --set alertmanagerFiles.api_url=PleaseInsertPrettyPlease --dry-run
```

**Update 4/9:** I've decided to move the receivers block into a separate file that's encrypted and stored securely.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your case, it's a very complex `--set` parameter, because you are trying to set something that's being already inserted by your yaml file which already declines from a template. I was looking into `values.yaml` looking for that parameter when I found in [Line 1091](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/609560713f68f6f88cc5e7ae744d306a555a1681/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L1091) as `slack_api_url` but in a different position, nested under global. Were you aware of that?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I should've been scanning through the values file instead of the readme configuration section. I'm going to play with this and see if I can get it going.

Comment: No worries, This will be of your interest too: [alertmanager-configmap.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/templates/alertmanager-configmap.yaml), This in conjunction with the values parameters i mention above will help you. Although I don't think it can be done as you are asking. I'd like to ask you: Running a command to change this url after it has been deployed would be an acceptable option?

Comment: running the command to change the URL after its been deployed is definetly an option that I want to have. My primary objective is to hide those keys from the config files (e.g., slack key, pager duty key etc)

Comment: did you saw the solution I proposed? If it was helpful, would you consider upvoting it as a recognition that it was well researched and time consuming. This way you enable others to get help with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running the command to change the URL after its been deployed is definitely an option that I want to have.

I'd like to write this answer to give you this option!

- You can chain a few commands with [SED](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to edit data on that ConfigMap (it's very similar to what `kubectl edit` does!)
- For that you will need to use the string deployed on the `customALM.yml`. For this example I set the parameter as `api_url: ChangeMeLater` before deploying.
- Then I deployed the chart with `helm install test-release stable/prometheus -f customALM.yml`
- Lastly we run:

```
kubectl get cm <CONFIG_MAP_NAME> -o yaml | sed -e "s,<OLD_VALUE>,<NEW_VALUE>,g" | kubectl replace -f -
```

- Explaining what's going on:

  - `kubectl get cm <CONFIG_MAP_NAME> -o yaml |` = gets the deployed configmap in yaml format and pipe it to the next command
  - `sed -e "s,<OLD_VALUE>,<NEW_VALUE>,g" |` = use `sed` to replace  `old_value` for `new_value` and pipe it to the next comand
  - `kubectl replace -f -` = use the output from the last command and replace the object currently deployed with the same name.
- I'll leave an example here step by step to elucidate more:

```
$ helm install test-release stable/prometheus -f customALM.yml
Release "test-release" has been installed. Happy Helming!
...

$ kubectl get cm
NAME                                   DATA   AGE
test-release-prometheus-alertmanager   1      44m
test-release-prometheus-server         5      44m

$ kubectl get cm test-release-prometheus-alertmanager -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  alertmanager.yml: |
    global: {}
    receivers:
    - name: slack
      slack_configs:
      - api_url: ChangeMeLater
        channel: someChannel
        text: Text message template etc.
    route:
      group_interval: 5m
      group_wait: 10s
      receiver: slack
      repeat_interval: 30m
      routes:
      - continue: true
        group_wait: 10s
        match_re:
          severity: error|warning
        receiver: slack
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-10T13:41:15Z"
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-11.0.6
    component: alertmanager
    heritage: Helm
    release: test-release
  name: test-release-prometheus-alertmanager
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "218148"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/test-release-prometheus-alertmanager
  uid: 323fdd40-2f29-4cde-833c-c6300d5688c0

$ kubectl get cm test-release-prometheus-alertmanager -o yaml | sed -e "s,ChangeMeLater,theurl.com/any,g" | kubectl replace -f -
configmap/test-release-prometheus-alertmanager replaced

$ kubectl get cm test-release-prometheus-alertmanager -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  alertmanager.yml: |
    global: {}
    receivers:
    - name: slack
      slack_configs:
      - api_url: theurl.com/any
        channel: someChannel
        text: Text message template etc.
    route:
      group_interval: 5m
      group_wait: 10s
      receiver: slack
      repeat_interval: 30m
      routes:
      - continue: true
        group_wait: 10s
        match_re:
          severity: error|warning
        receiver: slack
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-10T13:41:15Z"
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-11.0.6
    component: alertmanager
    heritage: Helm
    release: test-release
  name: test-release-prometheus-alertmanager
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "219507"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/test-release-prometheus-alertmanager
  uid: 323fdd40-2f29-4cde-833c-c6300d5688c0
```

You can see that the command changed the `ChangeMeLater` for `theurl.com/any`.

I'm still thinking about your first option, but this is a good workaround to have in hand.

If you have any doubt let me know!

Comment: This is actually a perfect solution right now. I have it running through a pipeline so after helm3 does it's thing, I have a follow up step that updates the configmap with an env variable that's secured as a secret. Great job on this answer A++!